# Express not creating app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm

I have run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g express-generator@4
```

However when I get to the following command, it does nothing:

```
express /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am following this guide: https://github.com/expressjs/generator and I can see that the express directory exists within node-modules.

Comment: what do you mean it does nothing? not even an error? it surely has to do something

Comment: I have seen no error or message. However it does not change the directory.

Comment: When I run "express --help" or "express --version" it doesn't return anything or any error messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
1) npm install -g express-generator

2) mkdir myExpress app

3) express -e --css stylus
```

Options:

-h, --help          output usage information

-V, --version       output the version number

-e, --ejs           add ejs engine support (defaults to jade)

-H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support

-c, --css   add stylesheet  support (less|stylus|compass) (defaults to plain css)

-f, --force         force on non-empty directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this line of code installs express into /tmp/foo, then changes the directory to /tmp/foo. What I do from the terminal is cd into the path I want to create my express app and run `express folderName && cd folderName` where folderName stands for whatever the name you want to name your folder.Then do `npm install` to update your package.json and proceed as normal with your starter app.